# Is there a LaTeX equivalent symbol to Unicode 'SYMBOL FOR NULL'

Tags: symbols, unicode

I'm looking for a LaTeX symbol that has the letters 'NUL' in a single character width. It's a pretty representation for what's often entered as `\0` in C-derived programming languages as the string termination character. In Unicode, this is represented as [code point U+2400](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x2400).

To be clear, I'm not looking for:

- `\varnothing`
- `\emptyset`
- and *definitely not* `\phi`!

I should also be clear that I'm looking for a *representation* of a control character, to print or display it rather than have it perform its intended function *as* a control character.

As a strongly related side question, assume I know the code point of a Unicode glyph. Is there a way to determine what the glyph's equivalent is in LaTeX? I'm relatively new to LaTeX typesetting, so I haven't yet found such a reference.

Comment: Use a [font that has the character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2400/fontsupport.htm).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: I'm sure there's another more recent duplicate as well, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on `pdflatex`, you can use the `ascii` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ascii}

\begin{document}

Is this it? \NUL

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also input the symbol directly as Unicode, so the code can be portable to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ascii}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{␀}{\NUL}

\begin{document}

Is this it? ␀

\end{document}
```

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`, find a font with the character and then do like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newfontface{\ASCIICONTROLS}{FreeMono} % <--- or another font
\newunicodechar{␀}{{\ASCIICONTROLS ␀}}

\begin{document}

Is this it? ␀

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If a TeX engine is used with Unicode/OpenType font support, then it is just a matter to find a font that contains the Unicode code point U+2400, e.g.:

```
% lualatex or xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\def\test#1{#1:&\fontspec{#1}\symbol{"2400}\\}
\begin{tabular}{l@{ }l}
  \test{FreeMono}
  \test{FreeSans}
  \test{FreeSerif}
  \test{Quivira}% http://www.quivira-font.com/
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted it to conform to the current font, both in size and style, you could build your own:

```
\documentclass[a2]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\NUL{\scalerel*{$\Shortstack[l]{N \phantom{N}U \phantom{NU}L}$}{X}}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
This is \NUL

\normalsize
This is \NUL

\itshape
This is \NUL

\upshape\ttfamily
This is \NUL

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the symbol always in bold, for clarity, then

```
\newcommand\NUL{\scalerel*{$\bfseries\Shortstack[l]{N \phantom{N}U \phantom{NU}L}$}{X}}
```

would remedy that:

[image]